# How to restart session in Symfony2

Tags: php, session, symfony

How can I restart session when a user clicks anywhere? I created a request listerner:

```php
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();
        //$event->getRequest()->getSession()->start();
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're actually after:

```
$session->invalidate();
```

Right?

Answer (score 4):

working correctly.

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $event->getRequest()->getSession()->migrate();
}
```

thanks.